# Remove base pairs

Tags: r

I need to remove some [base pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_pair) from a fasta file. This is the example of my input file

```
>\>NODE_1
GTTGGCCGAGCCCCAGGACGCGTGGTTGTTGAACCAGATCAGGTCCGGGCTCCACTGCAC
GTAGTCCTCGTTGGACAGCAGCGGGGCGTACGAGGCCAGCTTGACCACGTCGGCGTTGCG
CTCGAGGCCGGTCATGAACGCGGCCTCGGCGAGGGCGTTCTTCCAGGCGTTGCCCT  
\>NODE_2 
GTTGGCCGAGCCCCAGGACGCGTGGTTGTTGAACCAGATCAGGTCCGGGCTCCACTGCAC
GTAGTCCTCGTTGGACAGCAGCGGGGCGTACGAGGCCAGCTTGACCACGTCGGCGTTGCG
CTCGAGGCCGGTCATGAACGCGGCCTCGGCGA
```

and i have 20 these kinds of nodes in my file. My aim is to shorten the file like this

```
>\>NODE_1
GTTGGCCGAGCCCCAGGACGCGTGGTTGTTGAACCAGATCAGGTCCGGGCTCCACTGCAC
GTAGTCCTCGTTGGACAGCAGCGGGGCGT  
\>NODE_2 
GTTGGCCGAGCCCCAGGACGCGTGGTTGTTGAACCAGATCAGGTCCGGGCTCCACTGCAC
GTAGTCCTCGTTGGACAGC
```

Right now, I am just able to read the files in R.

```
x<-readLines("input file.fa", n = -1L, ok = TRUE, warn = TRUE)
```

Can you guide me how can i proceed this?

Comment: What does it mean to remove base pairs? I have not studied genetics...

Comment: For people with no biology background, I think you should clarify what a base-pair is (eg. how you are shortening your node by removing it).

Comment: I've added a link so long, but please clarify the question to make it easier for people to help.

Comment: ARG! Sorry, was my previous copy xO

Comment: Updated link to wiki.  I don't see the sequence shortening logic in your example, the 1st 60bp are constant, why are the next sequences shortened? they are not complimentary in any dimension ..

Comment: here in the question base pair means "ATGCCGGCCC". In this i want to remove some of these base pairs from each node(e.g NODE_1).

Answer (score 4):

For a base-R solution, use `substr`. Yet the better idea is to use Bioconductor's [Biostrings](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.2/bioc/html/Biostrings.html)' functions, i.e.

```
readFASTA("input.fa")->x
shortX<-subseq(x,start=1,width=100)
writeFASTA(shortX,"output.fa")
```